# How to fix this ActionListener to pass back the String to the widget

Tags: java, actionlistener, jtextfield, jtextarea

I am really new in Java, and just practising ActionListeners.  As the part of the application I work on, I will have a JTextField that lets the user to search a name, and then a JTextArea to show the result of the search.  I have a api for searching and fining the the names, only problem is to connect the widgets to the methods and action listener file.

Here is some parts of the code:

Widget File:

```
//Text Field
JTextField searchbox = new JTextField();
leftSide.add(searchbox, cnt);

String userText = searchbox.getText();
ActionListener sendsText = new SearchListener(search box);
searchbox.addActionListener(sendsText);


//TextArea              
JTextArea stationList = new JTextArea(12, 0);
leftSide.add(stationList, cnt);

String entered = userText;
stationList.append(entered);
```

SearchListener:

```
    public class SearchListener implements ActionListener {
      private JTextField searchbox;
      private JTextArea stationList;


    public SearchListener(JTextField search box) {
        this.searchbox = searchbox;
    }
    public void ListF(JTextArea stationList){
        this.stationList = stationList;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
       XXXX<NAMES> stations = HHHH.SimilarNames(searchbox.getText());

        for (NAMES station : stations) {
            //System.out.println(station);

*Problem*>    String result = (searchbox.getText());
*Problem*>    stationList.append(result);

    }
```

So in this program, the TextFiels is connected and the ActionListener working, but it prints out the list on Similar names in the CMD, (I commented it here). But I want it to send the list back to the Text Area in the API.(Widget File).  So I am not sure my ActionListener method at the top of the SearchListener is right. Also the *Problem*> in the code is where I tired to pass the search result to the text field, which doesnt work.

So anyone know how to fix it?

Thank is advance.

Comment: Don't you want to do something like `stationList.append(station)` instead of using the text from `searchBox`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I thought of that, but on Eclipse it gives an error: The method append(String) in the type JTextArea is not applicable for the arguments (NAMES)

Comment: Does `NAMES` have a method that returns `String`??

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, it gives the names (Strings).

Comment: You'll need to supply the append method with the String form of NAMES, for example, stationList.append(NAMES.toString()); or what ever method you have for returning a String representation of NAMES

Comment: @MadProgrammer I did that but it gives another error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method toString() from the type NAMES.   I tried station instead of NAMES for toString() and there seems no error to compile, but when I run the App and search for a word it gives lots of errors in CMD.

Comment: Did you use `station.toString()`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes and also stations.toString()

Comment: NAMES needs to provide a method that can return a `String` representation of itself (such as `getName` for example), then you would be able to use `station.getName()` to append it to the text area

Comment: @MadProgrammer I had a look at the API documentation and found three methods: **1- int** `getLocationID()` Get the numeric ID of the weather station
 **2- java.lang.String** `getLocationName()` to Get the human-readable name of the weather station
 **3- java.lang.String** `toString()`

Comment: Check the answer I've left.  Sounds like you need to use `station.getLocationName()`

Comment: I tried `station.getLocationName()`  and `station.toString()`, but compiles but get error when try to test the function.

Comment: The first error in CMD is _at SearchListener.actionPerformed(SearchListener.java:53)_

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think The problem is in sending back the data, I mean does the method ListF really sends the result to the widget in another class??

Comment: Without a runnable example, it's impossible to know.  It sounds like it's an issue with the data retrieval more then it is with the `ActionListener`.  Are you using a open API or one you've constructed?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yh, I know. It's an pre designed API. I only have a .Jar file, and documentation. anyway it works fine on CMD but I got to make it working by widgets.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be twisting a few things around, but perhaps this is what you're trying to accomplish:

A search field who's value determines what the text area is populated with.

If this is the case, then a few things have to change.  First, only code within the ActionListener will be axecuted upon UI events, so there is no reason to call `getText()` on any of the UI elements during initialization.

Second, adding a button to this UI greatly simplifies the logic here.  If attaching the listener to the search box, issues begin to arise such as "when do I know the user is done entering text?" and "How do I handle partial text?", however using a "Search" button puts this logic in the hands of a user.

Once the "Search" button is clicked, the action event from the listener that is attached to the button will trigger, and the `stationListArea` will be populated with the results of `similarNames(<text from search box>)`.

Note that though what is shown below is not the cleanest way to perform this task (which would involve fields and anonymous inner classes), it is straightforward and easy to understand.

Widget (not sure what `cnt` was, so I omitted in in sample code below)

```
//Create the search text box
JTextField searchBox = new JTextField();
leftSide.add(searchBox);

// Create a button that will serve as the "Action" for the search box
JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");
lefSide.add(searchButton);

// Create the station-list text area that will display text
//  based on results from the search box
JTextArea stationListArea = new JTextArea(12, 0);
leftSide.add(stationListArea);

// Create a listener that listens to the Button, then performs an
//   action from the search box to the text area
ActionListener searchButtonListener = new SearchListener(searchBox, stationListArea);
searchButton.addActionListener(searchButtonListener);
```

SearchListener

NOTE: Logic here will continue adding text into your `stationListArea` every time the button is clicked and `HHHH.SimilarNames()` returns a value.  To have the `stationListArea` just update with the new text every time, replacing the old, add a `stationListArea.setText("")` at the beginning of `actionPerformed()`.

```
public class SearchListener implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField searchBox;
    private JTextArea stationListArea;

    public SearchListener(JTextField searchBox, JTextArea stationListArea) {
        this.searchBox = searchBox;
        this.stationListArea = stationListArea;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        XXXX<NAMES> stations = HHHH.SimilarNames(searchBox.getText());

        for (NAMES station : stations) {
            stationListArea.append(station);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated based on feedback in main comments**

Your `NAMES` object needs some way to provide a `String` representation of itself.  This way, you can then append that value to your text area..

```
public class SearchListener implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField searchbox;
    private JTextArea stationList;

    public SearchListener(JTextField search box) {
        this.searchbox = searchbox;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        XXXX<NAMES> stations = HHHH.SimilarNames(searchbox.getText());

        for (NAMES station : stations) {
            stationList.append(station.getLocationName()());
        }

}
```